# If $f$ is a holomorphic function then $|f|$ is strictly sub-harmonic.

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

I got this problem in an exam and it looks so simple. Of course the cauchy’s formula for a holomorphic function $f$ allows one to say that $|f|$ is sub harmonic. But I am not able to see why it should be strictly sub-harmonic.

Any help or hint would be appreciated.

Comment: What if $|f|$ is harmonic?

Comment: Take $f\equiv 1$ for a counterexample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\overline {B}(z,r) $ be contained in the domain of $f$. Theb $f(z+re^{i\theta}) =\sum a_n(re^{i\theta})^{n}$ where $a_n=\frac {f^{(n)}(z)} {n!}$. Integrating w.r.t.  $\theta$ from $0$ to $\pi$ we get $f(z)=\frac 1 {2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} f(z+re^{i\theta})d\theta$. Hence $|f(z)|\leq \frac 1 {2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} |f(z+re^{i\theta}|d\theta$. This proves that $|f|$ is subharmonic. Now suppose equality holds. Then  $f(z+re^{i\theta})$ is real (and has the same sign) for all $\theta$. Apply MMP to $e^{if}$ and $e^{-if}$ to conclude that $f$ is a constant on $B(z,r)$ (and hence on the entire domain of $f$ as log as the domain is connected). This proves that $|f|$ is strictly subharmonic unless $f$ is a constant.
Of course constants are holomorphic but $|f|$ is not strictly subharmonic when $f$ is a constant.

Comment: How does the MMP give $|f(z)|\leq |f(z+re^{i\theta})|$ for all $\theta$? I think the MMP would only give us that inequality (strict) holds for some $\theta$.

Comment: @WhoKnowsWho I have edited my answer.

Comment: I still don’t see how it follows from the equality that $f(z+re^{i\theta})$ is real and has the same sign for all $\theta.$

Comment: @WhoKnowsWho If $|\int_a^{b} f(t)dt|=\int_a^{b}|f(t)|dt$ then $f(t)$ is real valued and does not change sign in $(a,b)$.

Comment: Ohhh! Yes, I am sorry. I missed such a simple point.